# Laptop won’t boot after installing CUDA tookit

Tags: windows, bitlocker, nvidia-geforce, cuda

Today I installed the CUDA toolkit on my laptop (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070 graphics card).
After a restart my laptop won’t boot anymore.

I, nor the CUDA installer, created a System Restore Point. I tried using the MediaCreationTool to repair my Windows partition, but since I’m using BitLocker, I’m unable to repair it (Cannot install Windows in this hard disk space, BitLocker-encryption is enabled for the selected partition).
I also tried booting in safe mode, but

Does anyone know how to repair, perhaps uninstall the graphics card driver from, my Windows partition in order to get it working again, without having to reinstall everything again?

Comment: Do you have a recent disk image?

Comment: No, I gave up and reinstalled Windows, and my applications yesterday.